# Reverse of number (numerical)

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

You can find reverse number $R$ using $x_{n+1} = x_n(2 - x_n \cdot R) \ \ $ where $ n = 0,1,..$

Prove it using Newton method for finding $0's$ of some function $f$

Anyone have idea what **that** function $f$ might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Newton iteration is
$$
x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}
$$
and to find the inverse you should root-find $f(x) = 1/x - R$ which has a root at $1/R$. Note that $f'(x) = -1/x^2$ so $f(x_n)/f'(x_n)$ will give you exactly the iteration you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x) = R - \frac{1}{x}. \;$ You find the simple derivation of your recursion formula [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Multiplicative_inverse_of_numbers_and_power_series)